# Catching mouse events for a custom SplitContainerDesigner

Tags: vb.net, .net-2.0, splitcontainer, design-surface

I'm trying to create a user control that will provide a draggable splitter between two panels — exactly like SplitContainer — in a custom IDesignerHost implementation. SplitContainer itself, as far as I can tell, is not an option; it will raise an exception unless used in Visual Studio's Designer.

My implementation would look roughly like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2701543/winforms-alternative-to-splitcontainer/2701836#2701836), except that I'm not receiving the necessary mouse events. I've tried event handlers, `On*` overrides and overriding `WndProc` in the user control itself, the host control, and the parent form, but I don't appear to receive `WM_MOUSEMOVE`, `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` or `WM_LBUTTONUP` events *anywhere*. Per [this bug report](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/94689/mouse-events-consumed-not-raised-in-2-0-designers?wa=wsignin1.0), I should be receiving `WM_MOUSEMOVE` in "the control designer"; I'm not sure what that refers to in this case.

Any ideas how I can implement a draggable splitter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is easy — once you know how.

1. Set the `Designer` attribute on the control to a custom class that inherits from `ControlDesigner`.
2. Override the `OnSetCursor` method so that, while over the splitter region, you show the `HSplit` or `VSplit` cursor, respectively. [Per this ticket](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/164920/changing-cursor-in-onsetcursor-in-derived-controldesigner), make sure *not* to set the control's cursor (this will cause a stack overflow, crash, or other erratic behavior, and certainly not what you want), but rather `Cursor.Current`.
3. Override `OnMouseDragBegin`, `OnMouseDragMove` and `OnMouseDragEnd` to resize the inner panels.