# Windows Forms: Using a user control like a container control

Tags: .net, winforms, user-controls

I have developed a simple **Windows Forms User Control**. I drag and drop this user control on a form. How can I achive, that now I can put further controls from the toolbox dirctly on the user control in the form?

In other words, is it possible to use a user control like a **container control**?

Answer (score 4):

> is it possible to use a user control like a container control?

No.

You design the UC using its own files.

When you drop an *instance* of the UC on a Form, that instance is **not** usable as a Container/Parent.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently it is [possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2694889/user-control-as-container-at-design-time)...